# Embedded NativeScript on a native iOS/Android app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have to develop an app for iOS and Android and it has to be able to run embedded in existing apps. I would usually do this with Cordova since it takes care of the multiple platforms and it is easy to embed in an existing app by creating a Cordova WebView.

Since this app is making heavy use of animations I have been playing around with NativeScript in order to avoid the bad performance of this kind of UI running on a WebView.

The problem is that it seems that embedding a NativeScript app in a native app is not straightforward at all. I have found this https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/nativescript/4kDFcX6gtxA/vdjruLLVBQAJ Is this still true? Any suggestions or ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this sample for iOS:
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-embedded

We will provide soon similar for Android

[UPDATE] Here is how to use {N} in existing Android app:
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-runtime-embedded-POC

Comment: Thanks a lot, that example looks awesome. Are there any limitations or particularities to take into account when embedding the TNSRuntime instead of having a full NativeScript app?

Comment: A known limitation is that currently the sample app is working with version 2.0.1 of the iOS runtime or lower.

Comment: Thanks @MihailSlavchev, we will stick to 2.0.1 for now then. I guess you guys are already looking into making the embedded runtime work with the latest version ;-)

Comment: Well, just saw this related issue opened 1 hour ago https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/607 I love you guys, with this first class support I can't see why NativeScript won't become the de facto standard for cross platform with native UI performance.